# Prove that wheel (Wn) graph family are hamiltonian

Tags: graph-theory, computer-science

- I need to determine and prove that wheel (Wn) graph family are hamiltonian.

  - I know that the Wn graphs are hamiltonian where it's possible to create a cycle that contains all the vertices, but **How to prove it?**

Answer (score 1):

It should suffice that you describe an algorithm that always generates a Hamilton cycle in any wheel.